# jquery geoplugin usage problem

Tags: jquery, geolocation, ip-geolocation

```
$.getJSON("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=117.201.92.17",function(data){alert(data);});
```

This code runs fine, but the response of the url, is empty. However if i visit the same URL by copy pasting the url it works. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this page (link)](http://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/json):

> **AJAX and Error: Invalid label**
>
> If you are using jQuery for example to
>   do AJAX calls to the JSON webservice,
>   you will probably be seeing the
>   Javascript error Error: Invalid label 
>   To eliminate this error, tag
>   jsoncallback=? onto the url when
>   making the jQuery Ajax call to any
>   JSON webservice  eg
>
> ```
> $.getJSON("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?jsoncallback=?",
> function (data) {
>   for (var i in data) {
>       document.write('data["i"] = ' + i + '<br/>');
>   }
> );
> ```

So I added that and [created a fiddle here (link)](http://jsfiddle.net/6KXFf/) to show it working.

Answer (score 0):

Docs on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ state:

> Important: As of jQuery 1.4, if the
>   JSON file contains a syntax error, the
>   request will usually fail silently.
>   Avoid frequent hand-editing of JSON
>   data for this reason. JSON is a
>   data-interchange format with syntax
>   rules that are stricter than those of
>   JavaScript's object literal notation.
>   For example, all strings represented
>   in JSON, whether they are properties
>   or values, must be enclosed in
>   double-quotes. For details on the JSON
>   format, see http://json.org/.

Is the data being returned in a valid JSON format? Why not try the other approach of:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: callback
});
```

This way you could drop the json dataType and make sure the call is working returning any data, json or not.

Also remember that due to browser security restrictions, ajax requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.